# how to add validations in mini-login form without redirecting in header itself of magento

Tags: validation, magento, authentication

I am using default mini-login form in header and it works to logged in with correct details but whenever i enter wrong username and password then for validation it redirects to customer/login page which i don't want to use.
I want to do the validations like customer/login page but in header itself and don't want to redirect anywhere.
Please give suggestion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question doesn't appear to be about programming. Perhaps you need to improve the question or perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: it is also programming related question only

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself for validations as below :
In the form tag i have added an id :

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form-header">
```

then i put below script to validate it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form-header', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

and required classes in the input box
but now the question is :
when both fields are validate and email, password is not matching then it redirects to customer/login page that i don't want to redirect and it should stay on the same.